# PHP Rest Server not receiving $_POST when URLRequestHeader is set in flash

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

I'm sending a json string to a REST server and receiving one in return, The flash code I've used is as follows

```
        var urlLoader : URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
        urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
        urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);

        var header1 : URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        var header2 : URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        var header3 : URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("pragma", "no-cache");

        var urlRequest : URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
        urlRequest.requestHeaders.push(header1);
        urlRequest.requestHeaders.push(header2);
        urlRequest.requestHeaders.push(header3);

        urlRequest.data = session;
        urlRequest.contentType = "application/json";
        urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
```

When I don't add the custom request headers to the request, my server receives the POST data correctly. When I add the custom headers, POST is empty. What could be causing this?

Comment: Does your url contain a querystring?

Comment: Works correctly for me, can't reproduce the problem. Firebug shows data being sent... How are you checking data are sent ? How are you getting them ? Can you provide a sample of data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the data will be sent via POST, PHP won't populate the `$_POST` global array because you're using a Content-Type of `application/json`.

Try updating you Content-Type header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`:

```
var header1 : URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

And here as well, though you already set the header above:

```
urlRequest.contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

Comment: where should I specify that I'm sending json in the POST?

Comment: @Aks You have two options; the first is to use `$_POST` (by updating your Content-Type header) - with this, you'll submit something like `page.php?json=...your data...` and then, in `page.php`, you'll use `$json = json_decode($_POST['json']);`. The second option is to *not* use `$_POST`, instead you can use `$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));`. I haven't ever used the second option in a real-scenario, so I can't guarantee it'll work.